# I don't know how to perform this mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this table in mysql. But i dont know how obtain the data that i need.

I need the total balance that the day start. The first balance of the CP1, the first balance of the CP2...

Based on this table the result that i need is 5500, but if i use GROUP BY and SUM don't work properly. I need the total start balance and the final balance, based on this table the final balance for CP2 for example its 600. 100 of gain on his day. Sorry for the inconveniencias and thanks for the help i'm new in mysql.

| id | wallet | timestamp | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CD1 | 2021-04-19 00:03:12 | 1000 |
| 2 | CD2 | 2021-04-19 00:05:12 | 500 |
| 3 | CD2 | 2021-04-19 00:10:12 | 550 |
| 4 | CD1 | 2021-04-19 00:13:12 | 990 |
| 5 | CD2 | 2021-04-19 00:19:12 | 600 |
| 6 | CD3 | 2021-04-19 00:25:12 | 1000 |
| 7 | CD4 | 2021-04-19 00:40:12 | 3000 |

The result that I need its, 5.500 start balance and 5.590 the end balance.

The results that I need is the SUM of the first day balance for example, the first results in the table is:

| id | wallet | timestamp | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CD1 | 2021-04-19 00:03:12 | 1000 |
| 2 | CD2 | 2021-04-19 00:05:12 | 500 |
| 6 | CD3 | 2021-04-19 00:25:12 | 1000 |
| 7 | CD4 | 2021-04-19 00:40:12 | 3000 |

And I also need the total end balance of the day:

| id | wallet | timestamp | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | CD1 | 2021-04-19 00:13:12 | 990 |
| 5 | CD2 | 2021-04-19 00:19:12 | 600 |
| 6 | CD3 | 2021-04-19 00:25:12 | 1000 |
| 7 | CD4 | 2021-04-19 00:40:12 | 3000 |

Thanks for the help and sorry, I'm new in mysql.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: What columns are adding up to get 5.500 and 5.590?  It's really unclear.

Comment: I read 5 times. But I can't understand what you mean. Can u explain more clear.

Comment: Sorry, it's now more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand based on your expected result you do not want the `sum` but the first value of `balance` from the starting date and the end date.

For the first balance of the day you can use:

```
select id,wallet,cd_date,balance as start_balance 
from (
select id,wallet,cd_date,balance 
from balance_tbl order  by cd_date ASC limit 15 ) as a  
group by wallet ;
```

The limit inside the subquery is because I am using `MariaDB` version and it needs the limit clause inside the subquery when you are ordering.

For the end balance of the day you can use:

```
select id,wallet,cd_date,balance as end_balance 
from ( 
select id,wallet,cd_date,balance 
from balance_tbl order  by cd_date DESC limit 15 ) as a  
group by wallet ;
```

[image]

Working demo `MySQL 5.6` : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ee030/2

I remove the limit in subquery in the demo

Comment: it's possible to get the limit number in the query? its because I don't know the exact registers and these change evert minute.

Comment: MySQL 5.7.32. The query in the sqlfiddle don't work for me, give this error: SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column.

Comment: Based on your query I have fund the query that I need: select walletname, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(totalWalletBalance ORDER BY timestamp ASC), ',', 1) as initial_balance, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(totalWalletBalance ORDER BY timestamp DESC), ',', 1) as total_balance
from ( select id,walletname,timestamp, totalWalletBalance
from futures_stats WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2021-04-19 00:00:00' AND '2021-04-25 23:59:59' order by timestamp ASC ) as a
group by walletname ; Thanks for your help! :)